# CompilationTask.call() introduces ClassNotFoundException. Worked in JDK6, not in JDK7

Tags: java, java-7, java-compiler-api

After moving from JDK6 to JDK7, the next code fails with a *ClassNotFoundException*

```
CompilationTask task = cSysCompiler.getTask(null, cFileManager, cDiagnosticCollector, null, null, cUnitsToCompile);
boolean mSuccess = task.call();
Analyzer mAnalyzer = new Analyzer(); // Throws ClassNotFoundException
```

Work around:

```
ClassLoader mSystemClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
mSystemClassLoader.loadClass("ft.jopc.com.JavaBytecodeObject");
mSystemClassLoader.loadClass("ft.jopc.com.analyzer.Analyzer");
mSystemClassLoader.loadClass("ft.jopc.opccl.ClassLoaderListener");
…
ompilationTask task = cSysCompiler.getTask(null, cFileManager, cDiagnosticCollector, null, null, cUnitsToCompile);
boolean mSuccess = task.call();
Analyzer mAnalyzer = new Analyzer(); // No ClassNotFoundException
```

Does anyone know why After the call to task.call() classes can't be found anymore? It looks like the systemclassloader is changed in some way by the compiling task?

Comment: Are you actually *compiling* the classes that you are using *in the same class*? If so, then chances are that some caching behaviour change in Java 7 resulted in the problem and it *should not* have worked in the first place.

Comment: @Joachim The classNotFoundException happens for classes which already existed on the classpath before compiling

Answer (score 3):

We recently faced a similar issue with a custom implementations of JavaFileManager redefining (among other things)

```
public ClassLoader getClassLoader(final Location location)
{
    return getClass().getClassLoader();
}
```

Not sure why it was done that way, but as in your case, this worked fine under jdk6. We pinpointed the jdk7 issue to this function in part due to the fact it failed during unit tests (for which the classloader was Launcher$AppClassLoader) but worked fine in "production mode" (where the class is loaded by a custom classloader). Changing this function to use the StandardFileManager version or even just encapsulating it inside an empty URLClassloader, such as

```
return new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{}, getClass().getClassLoader());
```

fixed the issue.

Apparently it is related to the introduction URLClassloader, and thus AppClassLoader, being "Closeable" in jdk7, as appear in :

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 282 in URLClassLoader))    
Launcher$AppClassLoader(URLClassLoader).close() line: 282 [local variables unavailable] 
JavacProcessingEnvironment.close() line: 1257   
JavaCompiler.initProcessAnnotations(Iterable<Processor>) line: 1004 
JavaCompiler.compile(List<JavaFileObject>, List<String>, Iterable<Processor>) line: 821 
Main.compile(String[], String[], Context, List<JavaFileObject>, Iterable<Processor>) line: 439  
JavacTaskImpl.call() line: 132
```

Then, I must admit I do not find the javadoc really clear on this topic, but looking at jdk6 DefaultFileManager as well as jdk7 BaseFileManager, it seems rather clear the expectation was rather to provide a temporary file manager (thus the need to close "if possible") rather than a "generic use" one.

(I would be happy to learn about additional/best-practice references on the subject in any case)